# Converting Immutable to mutable list Java, is there any alternative?

Tags: java, list, collections, immutability

I have a method that returns an Immutable list. I want to add elements to it and that's why have to convert it to a mutable list. Currently, I am creating a new ArrayList out of the Immutable list as follows:

```
final List<someDTO> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(someDTO.getImmutableList());
```

Is there any better way of doing it like using some collections copy method, java streams, or anything like that?

Comment: Although the answers given are technically correct, the way you’re currently doing it is in fact the best way to do it.

Comment: Drop the second `<someDTO>`: `<>` is sufficient.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed, it is a very valid question.  Java offers `List.copyOf` to convert a mutable list to an immutable one (copying it if needed), but offers no method that inverts this logic (creating a mutable `List` only if the input isn't mutable already).  I was hoping some marker interface would indicate this, but no such luck.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in all honesty, that's as best as it gets, **but** another variant would be:

```
someDTO.getImmutableList().stream().collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: IMO, streams are relatively costly and for a trivial operation like this, hardly worth the overhead.

Comment: @Vasan as mentioned in the answer "in all honesty, that's as best as it gets" thus I do agree with you. I just thought I'd show another approach.

Comment: new ArrayList<>(yourList) ;

/n

no need to stream and collect it later.

Comment: Why is the new ArrayList<>(yourList) solution mentioned in the comments not accepted?